# What's the point of using empty string to set cache variable in CMake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I've seen different ways of setting / using Cache variables in Cmake.
What is the standard?

What's the point of setting an empty string (`""`) to the cache variable?

Example

```
set(NVTX_ROOT_DIR "" CACHE PATH "Folder contains NVIDIA NVTX")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the point of setting an empty string ("") to the cache variable?

It is not just **setting** a value for a CACHE variable.

Command flow `set(CACHE)` normally performs **two things**:

1. **Declares** the **parameter** (assigns description and possibly the type)
2. Sets the parameter's **default value**. (That is, if the parameter is already set, its value isn't changed).

Empty value for CACHE variable could mean that a **parameter** denoted by this variable is **not set**. Depending on the project which uses it, this could be interpreted as:

- Do not use functionality described by the parameter.
- Emit an error telling the parameter should be set by a user.

In CMake code checking the parameter could be implemented with simple `if(VAR)`:

```
if(NVTX_ROOT_DIR)
  # The parameter is set
else()
  # The parameter is not set
endif()
```

---

While `if(NVTX_ROOT_DIR)` is false even if the **variable** is **not set**, declaring the parameter is impossible without setting its value. So empty string as a default value is a logical choice for being able to use simple `if(NVTX_ROOT_DIR)` for check absence of the parameter's setting.

Comment: is there a place to understand cmake better (apart from the cmake official doc)? Thanks

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat You can start with the links in the CMake tag About section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmake/info). I also think [this](https://preshing.com/20170511/how-to-build-a-cmake-based-project/#the-configure-and-generate-steps) article is helpful to get started. Specifically, for your question, you often see the empty quotes cache variables used in conjunction with CMake's `find_path` and `find_package` commands, as seen [here](https://github.com/CEED/GLVis/blob/ab82359a9b8adb548369a9514c183703140bd7b2/CMakeLists.txt#L16).

Comment: Since NVTX_ROOT_DIR is deprecated (according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html - *_ROOT is to be used in favor of *_ROOT_DIR), since it is deprecated does it make sense to set values to it?